# swift парсинг и вывод JSON

Tags: swift

Приветствую всех, уважаемые!
Есть такой код:

```
import UIKit

class UchastokViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var uchLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uchText: UITextView!

    var baseURL:String = "http://mylandbroker.ru/api.php?action=getuchastok&nid="
    var mainUch = uchastok()
    var nid:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getUchastok()
        uchLabel.text = mainUch.uchTitle
        uchText.text = mainUch.uchBody
    }

    func getUchastok() {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseURL+nid)!)
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:  { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                self.parseJsonData(data)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJsonData(data: NSData){
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                let jsonLoans = jsonResult?["uch"] as! [AnyObject]
                for jsonLoan in jsonLoans {
                mainUch.uchNid = jsonLoan["nid"] as! String
                mainUch.uchTitle = jsonLoan["title"] as! String
                mainUch.uchBody = jsonLoan["body_value"] as! String
                //uchas.uchGeometry = jsonLoan["field_map4_geom"] as! String
                }

            } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

В `viewDidLoad()` я вызываю функцию `getUchastok()`, которая подключается к сайту, получает ответ в JSON, парсит его и результат записывает в переменную `mainUch`. После этого я хочу вывести в текстовые поля полученные данные, но не могу, так как переменная `mainUch` оказывается пустой. Данные получаю корректные, проверял через консоль. Подскажите, где я накосячил и почему не могу вывести полученные данные в текстовое поле и `UILabel`?

Answer (score 1):

У тебя кривая ссылка. baseURL+nid, т.к nid = "", то получается просто baseURL, если открыть ее через jsonViewer, там тоже покажет пусто.

Answer (score 0):

В момент отрисовки UI данные еще не получены, после получения данных, необходимо сделать обновление UI на DispatchQueue.main.

примерно так:

```
...

if let data = data {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.parseJsonData(data)
    }
}

...
```